# Discum disable console spam

Tags: python, discord, discum

I am using the Discum module of python, everything works but the console is spammed messages of the module, is there a way to disable this?
here is a simple code piece

```py
import discum
bot=discum.Client(token="atokenwhichisunneccesaryforthisquestion")

@bot.gateway.command
def pingpong(resp):
    if resp.event.message:
        m = resp.parsed.auto()
        if m['content'] == 'a cool message':
            print("whoop whoop anyone wrote a cool message!")


bot.gateway.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

yep, just modify the client initializing line to:

```py
bot=discum.Client(token="atokenwhichisunneccesaryforthisquestion", log=False)
```

note, this information is available in discum's docs:
https://github.com/Merubokkusu/Discord-S.C.U.M/blob/master/docs/using/Get_Started.md#initializing-your-client